# Find 30 day old files

Tags: powershell

I've created a script to find files that are a certain amount of days old. I'm using it to find files that are 30 days old but I'm trying to leave it open should I ever need to plug in a different amount of time.

After you feed this part of the script the information you'd like, it is supposed to create a text file of all the files that meet the criteria. I can find files that are `-lt` and `-gt` or `-le` or `-ge` but when I attempt to use `-eq`, I get no results. Any thoughts on what's wrong with the portion of my script listed below?

```
$Path = Read-Host "What path should I look at?"
$DaysOld = Read-Host "How many days old should the files I'm looking for be?"
$Currentdate = Get-Date
$Targetdate = $Currentdate.AddDays(-$DaysOld).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy')
Write-Host "The target date is $targetdate"
$SourceFolder = $Path
$files = Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse |
         Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -eq $Targetdate } |
         Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -eq $false } |
         ForEach-Object { $_.FullName } |
         Out-File $outfileCopy
```

Comment: Using the `-eq` operator matches the exact date and time down to the second.. it will never return any results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with using -eq is that datetime objects are down to the second, so is 8/22/2017 at 11:59:27 AM -eq to 8/22/2017 at 00:00:00 AM? No, no it isn't. What you could do to defeat that is to use the `.ToShortDateString()` method which outputs a string such as 8/22/2017.

```
$Path = Read-Host "What path should I look at?"
$DaysOld = read-host "How many days old should the files I'm looking for be?"
$Currentdate = get-date
$Targetdate = $currentdate.AddDays(-$daysOLD).ToShortDateString()
Write-Host "The target date is $targetdate"
$SourceFolder = $path
$files = Get-ChildItem $path  -Recurse| Where-Object {$_.lastwritetime.ToShortDateString() -eq $targetdate}|Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false} | ForEach-Object {$_.fullname}| out-file $outfileCopy
```

This approach should only be used when trying to match things from the same day, ignoring the time of day, and should not be used when looking for things that are less than, or more than (including -le and -ge) because it uses string evaluation instead of date evaluation.

**Edit:** I've been doing it wrong for years, and didn't even know. Many thanks to @Matt for pointing out the .date property of a `[DateTime]` object, which retains the object type, but zeros out the time aspects of it. Better answer: Use the .Date property to compare, and this should work for greater than and less than evaluations as well.

```
$Path = Read-Host "What path should I look at?"
$DaysOld = read-host "How many days old should the files I'm looking for be?"
$Currentdate = get-date
$Targetdate = $currentdate.AddDays(-$daysOLD).Date
Write-Host "The target date is $targetdate"
$SourceFolder = $path
$files = Get-ChildItem $path  -Recurse| Where-Object {$_.lastwritetime.Date -eq $targetdate}|Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false} | ForEach-Object {$_.fullname}| out-file $outfileCopy
```

Comment: I always use `().Date` for stuff like this. Keeps a datetimeobject but zeros the time.

Comment: I didn't even know, I'll update my answer presently. Thanks Matt!

Comment: I figured it had to do with the actual time of day in relation to the files. I wasn't sure how to get around that since I am super new to powershell. I'm going to try and incorporate these answers here in just a few minutes. Thank you so much!

Comment: `().Date` is much shorter than `get-date -h 0 -min 0 -s 0 -mil 0`. Thanks @Matt

Comment: @LotPings I always used `[datetime]::Today` for that purpose